# VBA create CSV from sheet named after Workbook

Tags: excel, vba, csv, naming

I am trying to create a new CSV file, named after the original workbook minus a few words in the title, from a sheet in my workbook. Currently I can't figure out how to name it after my workbook, let alone subtract a few words from the WorkBook title. To clarify: workbook name "abc def", want new CSV file to be named "abc"

```
    Sub SaveActiveSheet_CSV ()
    Dim myCSVFileName As String

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    myCSVFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "abcd"
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Copy

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=MyCSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWorkbook.Close

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End Sub
```

Any help would be duly appreciated

Comment: *Want the CSV file to be named same as the Workbook

Comment: Use this: myCSVFileName = ThisWorkbook.fullname & "abcd"

Comment: Try `myCSVFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "abcd.csv"`

Answer (score 0):

If, as you suggest, your current file is named "abc def" then you can use `Split()` to get the name of the new file. So you will need both `.Path` and `.FullName` properties.

Thus:

```vb
Dim myCSVFileName As String

myCSVFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Split(ThisWorkbook.Name, " ")(0) & ".csv"
```

or, alternatively:

```vb
myCSVFileName = Split(ThisWorkbook.FullName, " ")(0) & ".csv"
```